# What is the correct order for calling the process class with WaitForExit?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, process

I'm having a bit of trouble de-ciphering the msdn documentation.

I want to call the process class. If the process that the process class calls exits I want my code to exit but I want the "StandardOutput" and the "StandardError" to be written to a log file.

If the process that the process class calls hangs (and doesnt exit) I want my code to timeout and close the process after a certain timeout 'time' but I still want the "StandardOutput" and the "StandardError" to be written to a log file.

So I have this as my code:

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = exePathArg;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentsArg;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    try
    {
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit(timeToWaitForProcessToExit);

        StreamReader standardOutput = p.StandardOutput;
        StreamReader standardError = p.StandardError;

        retDirects.Add("StandardOutput", standardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        retDirects.Add("StandardError", standardError.ReadToEnd());    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //nothing to do with this yet
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            p.Kill();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of doing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly, you need a timer to set the timeout. This code might help you:

```
Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);

process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

bool execTimeout = false;

// this call back will be called when timer ticks, Timeout for process.
TimerCallback callBack = (_process) =>
{
    // if the process didn't finish exexuting
    // and the timeout has reached 
    // then kill the process.
    if (!(_process as Process).HasExited)
    {
        execTimeout = true;
        (_process as Process).Kill();
    }
};

int timeout = 4000; // 4 seconds
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(callBack, 
                                     process, timeout, Timeout.Infinite);

// block untill finishing executing [Sync calling]
process.WaitForExit();

// Disable the timer. because the process has finished executing.
timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

// if the process has finished by timeout [The timer which declared above]
// or finished normally [success or failed].
if (execTimeout)
{
    // Write in log here
}
else
{
    string standardOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string standardError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I dont understand this code :-(, I have no idea what line 8 means. Is that an anonymous method?

Comment: Well, you can make it as a normal function. Just take it out.